# Replace Date field if null with another date in a fixed width format file in Unix

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a fixed width file. It has two date fields at displacements date1 (1-8) and date2 (11-18) in each line. If date1 is empty or blank, I would like to replace date1 with date2.

Input:

```
a20201005xy20201209mnkm
b20201001dt20210526nhyg
c        mn20210217bgyt
d        yr20210314vfgy
```

Desired Output:

```
a20201005xy20201209mnkm
b20201001dt20210526nhyg
c20210217mn20210217bgyt
d20210314yr20210314vfgy
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin
  
while read -r line; do
  date1=`echo ${line:1:8}`
  date2=`echo ${line:11:8}`
  echo $date1 $date2
  if [[ ${date1} == " " ]]
    then
     sed -i 's/${date1}/${date2}/g' $line
  fi
done < replace
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Cyrus - Somehow your response and comments got deleted.

Comment: Tried all three suggestions

Comment: but they didn't work

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 3):

Cyrus had a good answer with `awk`. If you cannot use `FIELDWIDTHS=`, you can do the same thing with `substr()` and `sub()` which will be available with all `awk`s. You simply use `substr()` to check if all characters in the 8-character substring beginning with character 2 are whitespace (`[[:blank:]]`) characters. If they are you just replace them with the substring of 8-characters beginning at character 12, e.g.

```
awk '{
    if (substr($1,2,8) ~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/) {
        date = substr($0,12,8)
        sub(/[ ]+/,date,$0)
    }
}1' input.txt
```

(**note:** the `1` at the end is just shorthand for `print` the record)

If you would like to shorten it a bit, you can simply remove the `date` variable and do a direct substitution with `substr()`, e.g. `sub(/[ ]+/,substr($0,12,8),$0)`, but that may be a bit less readable.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `input.txt`, you would receive:

```
$ awk '{
>     if (substr($1,2,8) ~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/) {
>         date = substr($0,12,8)
>         sub(/[ ]+/,date,$0)
>     }
> }1' input.txt
a20201005xy20201209mnkm
b20201001dt20210526nhyg
c20210217mn20210217bgyt
d20210314yr20210314vfgy
```

Look things over and let me know if that will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution works as intended.

Comment: Glad it helped. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: wrt `/[ ]+/` - a blank isn't a regexp metachar so it doesn't need to be put in a bracket expression to make it literal in a regexp, it's already literal. You can just write `/ +/`. The only time a blank has any special meaning is when it's used as the only char in a field separator (not just a regexp) and THEN you'd need to put it in a bracket expression to make it literal.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/^[a-z][[:space:]]{8}/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  val2=substr($0,12,8)
  sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,val2,val)
  $0=val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/^[a-z][[:space:]]{8}/){   ##using match function to match from starting with small letter followed by 8 spaces.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)     ##Creating val which has matched sub string.
  val2=substr($0,12,8)              ##Creating val2 with sub string of 8 characters.
  sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,val2,val)     ##Substituting spaces in val with val2.
  $0=val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)  ##Creating current line with value of val and sub string of matched string.
}
1                                   ##Printing current line.
' Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

If `perl` happens to be your option, would you please try the following:

```
perl -pe '
    $date1 = substr($_, 1, 8);
    if ($date1 =~ /^\s+$/) {
        substr($_, 1, 8) = substr($_, 11, 8);
    }
' file > newfile
```

- The `-pe` option composes an awk-like one-liner by putting the immediate code
  as an argument.
- The variable `$_` is a default variable of `perl` which works as a pattern
  space of `sed`.
- The `substr($_, 1, 8)` function extracts the substring starting at offset
  1 and length 8 out of the string `$_` which holds the current line.
- The regex `/^\s+$/` tests if the variable `$date1` consists of blanks only.
- The `substr()` function conveniently works as an `lvalue` meaning
  it can be assigned. The statement `substr($_, 1, 8) = substr($_, 11, 8);`
  copies the right substring over the left substring.

If you have more fields to replace, it will be easy to modify the code above
to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use 'sed', would you please try the following:

```
$ sed 's/^\(.\)        \(..\)\(........\)/\1\3\2\3/' input.txt
a20201005xy20201209mnkm
b20201001dt20210526nhyg
c20210217mn20210217bgyt
d20210314yr20210314vfgy
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-awk` you may try this one-liner:

```sh
awk 'length($1)<8 {$0 = gensub(/[[:blank:]]+/, substr($2, 3, 8), "1")} 1' file

a20201005xy20201209mnkm
b20201001dt20210526nhyg
c20210217mn20210217bgyt
d20210314yr20210314vfgy
```